# Lambert Beer's law deviations

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, photochemistry, spectrophotometry

Can somebody explain as concrete as possible, how the change of **temperature** and the change of **pH**  leads to deviations of this law?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Lambert Beer law  apply for fixed temperature and pH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A compound **S** follows the Lambert-Beer law if the absorbance $E_\lambda$ **at a particular wavelength $\lambda$** is proportional to the concentration $c$ of **S**.

\[E_\lambda = \left(\frac{I_0}{I} \right) = \epsilon\cdot c \cdot d \]

A "deviation" is observed when the **real** concentration $c$ is different from the expected/assumed.

This may happen if

1. **S** is an acid or a base:

   - variation of the pH leads to (de)protonation and forms another species with a completely different absorption spectrum, or at least a different $\epsilon$ at the wavelength under observation
2. **S** undergoes a reaction to **S'** (with different optical properties) at elevated temperatures (or change of pH)
3. Decrease of temperature or change of pH leads to the formation of a turbid solution from which light is scattered into the detector